How to display meaningful names for intermediate operations in PyTorch computational graph visualization?
I'm trying to visualize the computational graph of my PyTorch model using torchviz. I want the nodes in the graph to display meaningful names for the intermediate computations. However, the graph only shows generic operation names like AddBackward0, MulBackward0, etc., which makes it hard to interpret.
I've tried using custom nn.Module classes and custom autograd.Function classes to label the intermediate steps, but the node names in the graph still don't reflect these custom names.
Here's a minimal example that demonstrates the issue:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchviz import make_dot

# Custom modules for intermediate computations
class CustomAdd(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x, y):
        return x + y

class CustomMul(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x, y):
        return x * y

class SimpleModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleModel, self).__init__()
        self.custom_add = CustomAdd()
        self.custom_mul = CustomMul()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(1, 1, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Intermediate computations using custom modules
        a = self.custom_add(x, x)      # a = x + x
        b = self.custom_mul(a, x)      # b = a * x
        out = self.linear(b)
        return out

# Instantiate the model
model = SimpleModel()

# Input tensor
x = torch.tensor([[2.0]], requires_grad=True)

# Forward pass
output = model(x)

# Compute loss
loss = (output - torch.tensor([[1.0]])) ** 2

# Backward pass
loss.backward()

# Visualize the computational graph
dot = make_dot(loss, params=dict(model.named_parameters()))
dot.format = 'png'
dot.render('simple_model_graph')

When I generate the computational graph using torchviz, the nodes are labeled with generic names:

I want the nodes corresponding to the intermediate computations (a and b) to display the custom names from my CustomAdd and CustomMul modules.
How can I modify my code so that the computational graph visualization displays meaningful names for the intermediate operations?
Can the nodes in torchviz be labeled with custom names corresponding to the intermediate variables or custom modules/functions?
